# how to return the user email

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have created post route to store posts in the database. It's a protected route so user can store post only after entering the login details. When I post in postman, I've seen that the user email is not  returned in the object. Even in the mongodb collection, I don't see the email associated with the post. How do I include the email as well with the post object. I don't want the user to enter the email again and again when posting because they have already logged in. So I kinda want to store the email automatically with the post. Hope I make sense. Can someone help me with this?

Right now the object is kinda stored like this in the posts collection in mongodb

```
_id: ObjectId("5f1a99d3ea3ac2afe5"),
text: "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. ",
user:ObjectId("5f1a99d3eac2c82afe5"),
age:20,
country:"India",
gender:"male",
date:2020-07-24T08:23:35.349+00:00,
__v:0
```

I want the email too in the above object.

Post model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema ({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    
    email: {
            type: String
    }
    ,
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    gender: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = Post = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema)
```

post route

```
const express = require('express');
const router =  express.Router();
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth')
const { check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
const User = require('../../models/User')
const Post = require('../../models/Post')
router.post('/', [auth, [
    check('text', 'Text is required').not().isEmpty()
]], async (req,res)=>{
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array()})
    }

   
    try {
        const user = await (await User.findById(req.user.id)).isSelected('-password')

    const newPost = new Post({
        text: req.body.text,
        name: user.name,
        user: req.user.id,
        age: req.body.age,
        country: req.body.country,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        email: req.user.email // this email is not stored with the post and I want this to be automatically posted in the collection without the user having to type it again to save the post
    })
    const post = await newPost.save();
    res.json(post);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error')
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

User model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Comment: It's not the answer to your question, but isn't the email stored in your `user` document? If it is you could grab it from there. But I'm not event sure if it's necessary to save the email at two different places ( `post` and `user` ) since you have the reference to the `user.id` in your `post` document.

Comment: actually, I need to send them back documents through email after they post their text to my database and it would be a huge pain to see which post belongs to which email that's why I want to have the email included

Comment: Could you please also include user model in question for better understanding?

Comment: @SagarPednekar added the user model too

Comment: `email: user.email`

Comment: nope still didn't get the email in the collection @prax

Comment: @helpmepiliizzz other filed  `user.name`are returned?

Comment: nope, that's not in the collection as well @prax

Comment: what is the body that you pass in route ('/') ? Are you sure email is being saved in user's collection ?

Comment: if it not able to get any of `user.feildname` ,it seems that it cant find the user in collection.Can you give sample response and also check the `req.user.id` is not null and is correct

Comment: it's actually /post and in the body, I pass text, age, gender, country. I don't pass email there. I want the email to be there automatically without the user having to type it again and again. Yes, I checked, the email is being saved in the user's collection. @Ibrahim

Comment: sample response from postman ```{
    "_id": "5f1aa92c977b7ab444dc1a",
    "text": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. ",
    "user": "5f1a8ff33f6481c924948",
    "age": 20,
    "country": "India",
    "gender": "male",
    "date": "2020-07-24T09:26:04.900Z",
    "__v": 0
}```

Comment: make the `name` and `email` field  `required:true`

Comment: but that would make the user having to enter the email and name manually for posting a post which is what I don''t want. I want it to be automatic. Isn't there any way to do that?

Comment: You dont have to take it manually just take the other field from the body at frontend and pass name and email in the route from backend

Comment: okay, so it won't be possible to check now in postman right? but I can do that later in frontend?

Answer (score 2):

Change `isSelected` to `select`

`const user = await (await User.findById(req.user.id)).isSelected(password')`

Comment: it didn't work. It's the same thing right, user and user1

Comment: see you got your result returned by `findbyid` in `user` and again you were assinging varibale user `user=user.id`  and then ascessing email from `user.email` now what i have done is that i store the result returned by `findByid` in user1.

Comment: the const user1 just returns true in console.log. I dont understand why that req.user.id gives the user id from the user collection but req.user.email doesn't return the user email

Comment: I tried adding this line in the model file ```email: {
            type: Schema.Types.String,
            ref: 'users'
    }``` but it still doesn't returns the email

Comment: no your schema is right already there is something wrong with request.

Comment: `.isSelected('-password')` what is this can you tell breifly?

Comment: yeah. I tried both req.user.email, user.email and user1.email. nothing gave the result that I wanted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218510/discussion-between-prax-and-helpmepiliizzz).

Answer (score 0):

What I potentially see the problem here is, once you have grabed the object of user, you're still referring to `req.user.email` instead of `user.email`.

If that does not solve your problem, try to console.log the user returned from after `User.findById`

**Update**:
You can see [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isSelected) that isSelected returns boolean. So you're essentialy getting `true` for having password field in `user`. Also instead of `req.user.email` use `user.email`

Comment: I console.logged user.email under the findById line and it says undefined. but when i just console logged user then it returned true

Comment: Ayyyee, What I see is your isSelected is returning true and false. Please remove isSelected for now and try again